# Yammer REST API - Get Messages from Group

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, yammer

I am trying to get all threaded messages from a group of yammer, but it seems that something wrong happened in the call.

The retrive all messages from the group I use this call:
**/api/v1/messages/in_group/{groupId}.json?threaded=true**

And when this call ends, I save the last message retrieved from the result and I execute the following call recursively until there is no more messages in the group: 
**/api/v1/messages/in_group/{groupId}.json?threaded=true&older_than={messageId}**

It seems that the process works correctly, but when you look the data that you have retrieved from Yammer, there is some messages that appear in the Yammer group Wall that have been not retrieved using the REST API.

Do someone know why the REST API is not getting all Yammer data?

Thank you so much!

Aleu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesjson, here is the intended functionality of threaded=true: "threaded=true will only return the thread starter (first message) for each thread. This parameter is intended for apps which need to display message threads collapsed. threaded=extended will return the thread starter messages and the two most recent messages all ordered by activity, as they are viewed in the default view on the Yammer web interface."

Based on your question, perhaps threaded=extended would give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but finally I solved the problem. I combined that threaded=true & treaded=false in two different calls and it worked! Otherwise, I think that your answer can solve the problem too. Thanks and sorry for the late response :)